# Enable errors PHP Wordpress 5.2

Tags: php, errors

Since Wordpress 5.2 can not display errors on the site.
The constants "*WP_DEBUG*" et "*WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY*" doesn't work.
The following message is always displayed : "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

Have you solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable this behaviour by setting `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` to `true`:

```
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
```

This will stop the "The site is experiencing technical difficulties" message from appearing, so errors will appear as they did prior to this feature being added.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am wrong here, but `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` is still available and works in installs 5.2 and after.

According to WordPress docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

> Starting with WordPress version 2.5, setting WP_DEBUG to true also raises the error reporting level to E_ALL and activates warnings when deprecated functions or files are used; otherwise, WordPress sets the error reporting level to E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_USER_NOTICE.

Edit: Here is how things play out in the back end. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/load.php#L321

There is nothing in there that says it is deprecated or being removed. And that error reporting level are set correctly.

I just tested it in my environment by setting **WP_DEBUG** to true inside of the wp-config.php file. And it gave the same *The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions* message, but also gave me the syntax error I put into my site to test and break it. I am running PHP 7.2

Comment: Codex is way outdated, so citing it for such a new functionality is probably not a good idea, as it might not get updated anymore

Comment: FWIW, the newer article doesn't mention it either: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: @kero, I've edited my response to also include what takes place in the backend when that constant is set. You can see that when WP_DEBUG is set to true, that it toggle error_reporting to E_ALL, which as pf PHP 5.4, will show every possible error.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this code on WordPress 5.2 `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`
and it is perfectly working. I think you should reinstall the WordPress.